# Not able to retrive the URL within the link of Shopify API Response headers for pagination using limit in core php

Tags: php, url, response, response-headers, shopify-api

I am not able to fetch the URL within the Link for pagination from the shopify Response headers . I will be a great help if somebody can help me to retrive the url in core php and implement pagination. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full response with us?

Comment: Thanks, John Sims for your reply, but mean while I was able to fetch the URL within the Link for pagination. Below is the code, which will be helpful to those who got stuck like me, which I wrote, in 2 Parts as not allowing me to submit the Answer and comment fields don't accept more characters.

Comment: <?php 
$api_key = "4a4b367388d6a342feedef5b8a2d2862";
$password = "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";
$shop = "radheshyampkori";
$api_endpoint = "/admin/api/2020-04/customers.json?limit=2&created_at_min=2020-06-25T00:00:01&updated_at_min=2020-06-25T00:00:01";  
$i = 1; 
echo "Records of Page Nos: ".$i; echo "</br>";
echo "================="; echo "</br>"; echo "</br>";echo "</br>";
$customer_data = get_response_data($api_key, $password, $shop, $api_endpoint);  
 $url_next = $customer_data[0];    
 $next_rel_link = $customer_data[1]; 
 $url_previous = $customer_data[2];

Comment: $previous_rel_link = $customer_data[3]; 
 $i = 2; 
 while($next_rel_link != '')    
 {
  $explode_pagination_url = explode("?",$url_next);  
  $api_endpoint_limit_portion = $explode_pagination_url[1];
  $api_endpoint = "/admin/api/2020-04/customers.json?".$api_endpoint_limit_portion;
  echo "Records of Page Nos: ".$i;  echo "</br>"; 
  echo "================="; echo "</br>"; echo "</br>";echo "</br>";
  $customer_data = get_response_data($api_key, $password, $shop, $api_endpoint);  
  $url_next = $customer_data[0];
  $url = $url_next;  
  $next_rel_link = $customer_data[1];

Comment: $url_previous = $customer_data[2]; 
  $previous_rel_link = $customer_data[3];  
  $i = $i + 1;
 }

Comment: function get_response_data($api_key, $password, $shop, $api_endpoint)
{
 $url = "https://" . $api_key .":".$password ."@". $shop . ".myshopify.com" . $api_endpoint;
 echo "Latest URL"; echo "</br>";
 echo $url; echo "</br>";
 if (!function_exists('curl_init'))
 { 
        die('CURL is not installed or it is not loaded!');
    }

Comment: shopcurl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
 curl_setopt($shopcurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $response = curl_exec ($shopcurl);
 curl_close ($shopcurl);
 echo "<pre>";print_r($response); echo "</pre>";
  $responseHeaders = get_headers($url,1);

Comment: $next_link = "";
 $previous_link = "";
   $url_for_next_records_with_pagination = "";
   $url_for_previous_records_with_pagination = "";
 if(array_key_exists('Link',$responseHeaders))
    {
       $link = $responseHeaders['Link'];  
       $link0 = $responseHeaders['Link'][0];  
       $link1 = $responseHeaders['Link'][1];  
     $checking_rel_previous_exists_with_location = strpos($link,'rel="previous"',0); 
     $checking_rel_next_exists_with_location = strpos($link,'rel="next"',0); 
     if(!empty($checking_rel_previous_exists_with_location))
     {

Comment: $pos_first_char_for_next_in_link = strpos($link, '<', 1); 
      $pos_last_char_for_next_in_link = strpos($link, '>', $pos_first_char_for_next_in_link);       
      $retrieved_next_url = substr($link, $pos_first_char_for_next_in_link + 1, -13);  
      $explode_value_of_pagination_url = explode(";",$link);      
      $first_portion_of_Link = $explode_value_of_pagination_url[0];      
      $previous_portion_of_Link = $explode_value_of_pagination_url[1];      
      $end_portion_of_Link = $explode_value_of_pagination_url[2]; 
     }

Comment: else
     {
       $pos_first_char_in_link = strpos($link, '<', 0);
       $pos_last_char_in_link = strpos($link, '>', 0);       
       $retrieved_next_url = substr($link, $pos_first_char_in_link + 1, $pos_last_char_in_link - 1); 
       $explode_value_of_pagination_url = explode(";",$link);       
       $first_portion_of_Link = $explode_value_of_pagination_url[0];       
       $end_portion_of_Link = $explode_value_of_pagination_url[1];  
     }  
   }

Comment: $url_for_next_records_with_pagination = $retrieved_next_url; 
   $next_link = $end_portion_of_Link;   
      return array($url_for_next_records_with_pagination, $next_link, $url_for_previous_records_with_pagination, $previous_link);
}
?>

Comment: Please remove your API key.

Comment: Now it is not removable as it is more than 5 mins. Also that is a test store which I have created for testing purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to get the next and previous links from Shopify's Link Response Header:

Let's suppose you got the link header in:

```php
$link_headers = '<https://xxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/collections/id/products.json?
limit=50&fields=id,tags&page_info=XYXYXY>;
rel="previous",<https://xxxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/collections/id/products.json?
limit=50&fields=tags&page_info=XYXYXYZ>; rel="next"';
```

Then you can use:

```php
$links_arr = explode(", ", $link_headers);
    
$cursor_links = [];

for($i=0; $i < count($links_arr); $i++) {
    $tmp = explode('; rel=', $links_arr[$i]);
    $cursor_links[trim($tmp[1], '"')] = substr($tmp[0], 1, -1);
}

var_dump($cursor_links);
```

Which returns:

```
array(2) {

   ["previous"]=> "https://xxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/collections/id/products.json?
                   limit=50&fields=tags&page_info=XYXYXY",

   ["next"]=> "<https://xxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/collections/id/products.json?
               limit=50&fields=tags&page_info=XYXYXYZ"

}
```